# Slick android ProguardCache error

Tags: android, scala, slick

I'm learning Scala and i want to test slick for Sqlite DB in Android.
I tried this template:

https://www.lightbend.com/activator/template/slick-android-example

but when tried to import the Project in Intellij, I got the follow error:

> \slick-android-example\build.sbt:28: error: not found: value ProguardCache
>     ProguardCache("slick") % "com.typesafe.slick"

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activator templates are extremely out of date. The proper syntax using the current version of sbt-android would be

```
proguardCache += "slick"
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed proguardCache entry and updated sbt to 0.13.6 and it worked